# Matlab Batch Processing for HDF data - Could not open file Error

Tags: matlab, batch-file, image-processing, hdf

Matlab batch processing for HDF data gives error. If i use single operation it perfectly works. But not working in batch operation. My code is here

```
files = dir('/upload/server/php/files/*.hdf');

for k = 1:numel(files)

    L_865 = hdfread(files(k).name, '/Geophysical Data/L_865', 'Index', {[1  1],[1  1],[6120  1243]});
    L_620 = hdfread(files(k).name, '/Geophysical Data/L_620', 'Index', {[1  1],[1  1],[6120  1243]});
    NDVI = (L_865- L_620) ./ (L_865 + L_620);
    NDVI=NDVI-min(NDVI(:));
    NDVI=NDVI./max(NDVI(:));
    [J,~]=gray2ind(NDVI);
    imwrite(J,jet,['/server/php/files/images/'files(k).name],'jpg');

end
```

Error is

```
Error using hdfread>dataSetInfo (line 348)
Could not open file 'OxxxST_S.hdf'.

Error in hdfread (line 209)
[hinfo,params] = dataSetInfo(varargin{:});

Error in batchndvi (line 7)
L_865 = hdfread(files(k).name, '/Geophysical Data/L_865', 'Index', {[1  1],[1  1],[6120
1243]});
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `dir` in a specific directory, `/upload/server/php/files/` to find your files.
You also later write out to the same directory (with `imwrite`).

However, you don't specify the directory when you use `hdfread`, so it probably can't find the file. You may have previously been in the correct directory when running the code, so didn't notice.  For a quick fix, you can just concatenate strings as you do with `imwrite`.

```
L_865 = hdfread([`/upload/server/php/files/`,files(k).name,], ...);
```